# Swift error: Int is not convertible to 'DictionaryIndex<Int,Int>'

Tags: swift

When I switched over from Xcode 6 beta 4 to beta 5 I got this error (Int is not convertible to 'DictionaryIndex') in reference to my `plays` variable. I don't know how to remedy this.

Here is the code block:

```
    var plays = Dictionary<Int,Int>()
    var done = false
    var aiDeciding = false


//Function that says what to do if a UIButton is clicked:

@IBAction func UIbuttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    if !plays[sender.tag] && !aiDeciding && !done {
        setImgforCircle(sender.tag, player:1)
        thinkingLabel.hidden = true
        thinkingLabel2.hidden = true
        thinkingLabel3.hidden = true

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is just a deceiving error message and the actual error is in

```
if !plays[sender.tag]
```

Instead, it should be

```
if plays[sender.tag] != nil
```

Comment: That fixed that error but now on the same line I get "Bool is not convertible to UIInt8". Any suggestions?

Comment: If I use your code and replace sender.tag with 0 or variable of NSInteger type, it compiles fine. I do get similar error if I try to pass Bool. So I am wondering if the problem is not with the sender.tag. What type is it and what is the value? Would it help if you explicitly casted it to Int?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a change in the language, specifically this

> Optionals no longer implicitly evaluate to true when they have a value
>   and false when they do not, to avoid confusion when working with
>   optional Bool values. Instead, make an explicit check against nil with
>   the == or != operators to find out if an optional contains a value.

`plays[sender.tag]` returns an `Option<Int>` and you are assuming that a `nil` value will evaluate to false, hence `!plays[sender.tag]`.

Since beta 5 this is forbidden and you have to explicitly check against `nil`

```
plays[sender.tag] != nil
```

Comment: Thanks, but now on that line I get the error, "Bool is not convertible to UIInt8"

Comment: @user3781199 very odd, it might be worth of another question.